# "MySQL functions missing" error from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using EasyPHP on Windows. When I try to run a script (from the command line), I'm having the following error:

> DB connection error: MySQL functions missing, have you compiled PHP with the --with-mysql option?

It was strange since all MySQL functions are working fine when running PHP scripts using HTTP. I checked my php.ini file and found all MySQL extensions there:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP CLI does not use the php.ini where the mysql extensions are enabled. Run `php --ini` on the command line to see which ini it uses and enable the extensions therein.